# AFURLSessionManager authentication

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, afnetworking

I'm trying to implement a simple file download method in my iOS app using AFNetworking. First I'm creating an `AFURLSessionManager`:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let manager = AFURLSessionManager(sessionConfiguration: configuration)
```

And then I'm creating and firing a download task:

```
let task = manager.downloadTaskWithRequest(request, progress: nil, destination: {
        (targetPath: NSURL, response: NSURLResponse) -> NSURL in

        // ...
        return fullPathURL

    }, completionHandler: {
        (response: NSURLResponse, filePath: NSURL?, error: NSError?) in

        // ...
})

task.resume()
```

When I run the application I get an error telling me that I'm not authorized to access the url:

```
NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)
```

I tried with `setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock`, but the block never gets called.

So the question is: How do I pass the credentials for basic http authentication using `AFURLSessionManager`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it: you need to use `setTaskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock` to handle authentication challenges on download tasks.